# Looping through file and trying to group values by keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with the following:

```
1   cdcdm
1   dhsajdhsa
2   ffdm
2   mdff
3   ccdfm
3   cdmfc
3   fmdcc
```

My goal is for the output to look like this:

```
1 : cdcdm, dhsajdhsa
2 : ffdm, mdff
3 : ccdfm, cdmfc, fmdcc
```

I wrote the following code, but for some reason, I'm not getting the expected output.

```
value_list = ''
cur_key = None
key = None
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    try:
        key, value = line.split()
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        if cur_key == key:
            value_list = value_list + "," + value
        else:
            if cur_key:
                print(cur_key + ":" +value_list)
                cur_key = key
                value_list = ''
            else:
                cur_key = key
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
1:,dhsajdhsa
2:,mdff
```

How can I modify my code to get this to work?

Thanks,

Mango

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimally changed implementation might look like this

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    cur_key = None
    value_list = []
    for line in f.readlines():

        key, value = line.split()
        value = value.strip()

        if not cur_key:
            cur_key = key

        if cur_key == key:       
            value_list.append(value)
        else:
            print(cur_key + ":" + ', '.join(value_list))
            cur_key = key
            value_list = [value]
    print(cur_key + ":" +', '.join(value_list))
```

output:

```
1:cdcdm, dhsajdhsa
2:ffdm, mdff
3:ccdfm, cdmfc, fmdcc
```

So we need to make sure `cur_key` has a value for the first iteration. So set it if not `None`. Also when we find a new key we shouldn't reset `value_list` to be blank. It should be the set to the value read on that line, so the lien is not skipped. Also to catch the final groups line we should print the values again outside the loop at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

with open('example.txt') as f:
    for key, strings in itertools.groupby(f, lambda s: s.strip()[0]):
        print('{}: {}'.format(
            key, ', '.join(s.split(None, 1)[1].strip() for s in strings)))
```

Here's a answer based on your code:

```
value_list = []
cur_key = None
f = open('example.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    key, value = line.split()
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()
    if cur_key == key or cur_key is None:
        value_list.append(value)
    else:
        print('{}: {}'.format(cur_key, ','.join(value_list)))
        value_list = [value]
    cur_key = key

if value_list:
    print('{}: {}'.format(cur_key, ','.join(value_list)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it by modifying my existing code?  I'm tyring to solve it in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend throwing that away and using a `collections.defaultdict`. Then you can add values to a list for the corresponding key, and print the completed dictionary when you're done:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.split()
        d[k].append(v.strip())

for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
    print('{} : {}'.format(k, ', '.join(v)))
```

Comment: I want the solution to be stateless. Is there a way to solve it without remembering the entire dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I also believe there are better ways to do it, but if you really want to stick to the basics, at least use lists instead of concatenating text. Here's yet another version of your code, with slight changes:

```
lists = []
cur_key = None
key = None
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    try:
        key, value = line.split()
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        if cur_key != key:
            if(cur_key):
                lists.append(value_list)
            value_list = []
            cur_key = key
        value_list.append(value)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
lists.append(value_list)

for i,l in enumerate(lists):
    print(str(i+1) + ' : ' + ', '.join(l))
```